# Show all columns from a DataReader

Tags: c#

I have a problem with this code. I want to show all data from column carte but it show's only the first row, what can I do?

```
        try{
            mcon.Open();  
            s = "select* from login.biblia where carte='"+Carte.Text+"'"; 
            mcd = new MySqlCommand(s, mcon);     
            mdr = mcd.ExecuteReader();

           if (mdr.HasRows)
            {
                while (mdr.Read())
                {
                    richTextBox1.Text = mdr[0].ToString();
                }

            }else
                MessageBox.Show("NO DATA");

    }catch (Exception ex)     
        {MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);}
        finally{  
            mdr.Close();                
            mcon.Close();}
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Build up a `StringBuilder` with all the records, and assign the result to your `RichTextBox`.

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();

while (mdr.Read())
    sb.AppendLine(mdr[0].ToString());

richTextBox1.Text = sb.ToString();
```

Answer (score 2):

You are setting the `Text` property of the richTextBox every time you use this line

```
richTextBox1.Text = mdr[0].ToString();
```

Instead you should add a return onto the end and append it instead. There are two ways to do this

```
richTextBox1.Text += mdr[0].ToString() + "\r\n"; //Version 1
richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text + mdr[0].ToString() + "\r\n"; //Version 2
```

Instead of `"\r\n"` you can also use `Environment.NewLine` which will add a new line for you. Examples:

```
richTextBox1.Text += mdr[0].ToString() + Environment.NewLine; //Version 1
richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text + mdr[0].ToString() + Environment.NewLine; //Version 2
```

Comment: Seems overly complicated when you could just use `StringBuilder`

Comment: @dcreight Maybe so, but everyone has their way of doing things, I am just trying to help the question asker understand his mistake, "use StringBuilder" is not helping them understand their mistake. My answer points out the mistake and explains the correct way to do what they were trying to do, not an alternative to it.